# Pandas get cell index by header and row names

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to acces cells by header and row names (size can vary)

```py
df = pandas.read_excel('file.xlsx')
print(df)

  id  A  B  C
0  D  1  2  3
1  E  4  5  6
2  F  7  8  1

# into this...

{
("A", "D") : "1",
("B", "D") : "2",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order is not important create `MultiIndex Series` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and then use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.set_index('id').unstack().to_dict()
print (d)
{('A', 'D'): 1, ('A', 'E'): 4, ('A', 'F'): 7, ('B', 'D'): 2, 
 ('B', 'E'): 5, ('B', 'F'): 8, ('C', 'D'): 3, ('C', 'E'): 6, ('C', 'F'): 1}
```

If order is important (python 3):

```
d = df.set_index('id').unstack().sort_index(level=1).to_dict()
print (d)
{('A', 'D'): 1, ('B', 'D'): 2, ('C', 'D'): 3, ('A', 'E'): 4, ('B', 'E'): 5, 
 ('C', 'E'): 6, ('A', 'F'): 7, ('B', 'F'): 8, ('C', 'F'): 1}

df1 = df.set_index('id')
c = np.tile(df1.columns, len(df1))
i = np.repeat(df1.index, len(df1.columns))
v = np.ravel(df1)

d = {(a,b):c for a,b,c in zip(c,i, v)}
print (d)
{('A', 'D'): 1, ('B', 'D'): 2, ('C', 'D'): 3, ('A', 'E'): 4, ('B', 'E'): 5, 
 ('C', 'E'): 6, ('A', 'F'): 7, ('B', 'F'): 8, ('C', 'F'): 1}
```

Comment: Very helpful and yet simple. What if id is not given? like it vary across files? (Im trying to write a diff for excel)

Comment: @mikazz - If `id` is not in data, what is expected output? Used original index, here `0,1,2` from `print (df.index)` ? Or then is used some default index? Whats happen?

Comment: @mikazz - then omit `.set_index('id')` only

Comment: Once Again... When I use just df.unstack().to_dict(), it shuffles rows and takes cells with Unnamed: 0 as index
('Unnamed: 0', 0): 'D', ('Unnamed: 0', 1): 'E',

Comment: @mikazz - I am a bit confused, can you change data sample for input Dataframe? `Unnamed: 0` is column name?

Comment: So. Everything stays the same, I just cleared id cell (D, E, F, header), then unstack() makes column with name:
Unnamed: 0 with (D, E, F ) as its values (I want this values to be my keys of dict, not vals)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204614/discussion-between-jezrael-and-mikazz).